# Get ID of row in SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have this statement in PHP

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stmt)) 
                {...
```

It returns the next objects in each row of the results. What I am wondering is, is there and identifier as to the result itself. I myself in the table have an ID but I wish to know if there is an ID for the specific results returned.

Edit: If not, is there an alternative function I can use other than sqlsrv_fetch_object that supports this?

Comment: Very short answer : no, there isn't.

Comment: is there an alternative function I can use other than sqlsrv_fetch_object that supports this?

Comment: Do you want the extra id to be part of the result set or to have your php object for the individual row some extra id property?

Comment: I want it to be part of the result, for example, if it were an array I could refer to its index.

Comment: You can use the windowing funtion ROW_NUMBER() in any query to generate a unique id for individual result sets (SQL server 2008)

Comment: Thank you, I decided to use this after all. Guess I can't choose a comment as an accepted answer :|

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by an identifier to the results (which result?). You mean `$stmt`? An alternative to that function is [sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

Ex:

```
$counter = 0;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt))
{
  //process row
  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt)) 
     {...

I've changed the code around and used fetch array instead, how do I access to index of the array? So, the row that $row would be on...

Comment: @Zizo47 Index of the `$stmt` array? You can do what @Mithrandir said about using `ROW_NUMBER()` in your query, or use a counter variable in your while loop (like my example edit).